# Javascript interpreter for Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, shell

Is there a way to run linux commands from javascript that uses a standalone interpreter (something similar with SpiderMonkey, JavaScript shell)?

Comment: Why don't you write it in bash?

Comment: Yes, that was the first option, but someone suggested me to use javascript, so thats why I'm wondering if it is possible or not. :)

Answer (score 11):

You could use NodeJS. It has a child_process module that can run arbitrary commands. E.G. [child_process.spawn()](http://nodejs.org/api.html#child_process-spawn-95)

When your script is finished you run it like this:

```
node myscript.js
```

Answer (score 8):

[jslibs](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/) is a standalone JavaScript interpreter that runs on Linux32/64 and Windows.
You can easily run linux commands through the libraries provided by [jslibs](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to define JS functions that will call your C/C++ functions that could use `system()` call, executing some linux commands.

- Spider Monkey's way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_C_Engine_Embedder's_Guide#Native_functions
- Google V8 is also an option: http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html#accesssors

So you would have

```
system('rpm -i myapp.rpm');
system('rpm -i myapp2.rpm');
```

or perhaps

```
install('myapp.rpm');
install('myapp2.rpm');
```

Comment: Yes, I need to run something like system('rpm -i myapp.rpm'), but directly from Javascript, because I can't depend on other languages, like C++ or Java.

Answer (score 0):

[Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) offers a JavaScript interpreter written in Java which can be called from the command line. If you need a browser emulator, try [Envjs](http://www.envjs.com/).

Rhino can't execute commands but you can use `org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.defineFunctionProperties()` to define a new function which calls some Java code in which you can create a new process using `ProcessBuilder`

[EDIT] Since JavaScript is an interpreted language, you need an interpreter. For the interpreter to run, you need some other language. Linux doesn't come with one built-in (like it does for shell scripts or similar).

If you need scripting, use Bash or (for more complex scripts) [Python](http://www.python.org/).

Comment: I don't need a browser emulator. All I want to do is run a javascript file (using an interpretor) that runs some linux commands. Is it possible to do this? And also I would prefer not to depend on Java, because my javascript file should make some installations on my linux machine. I don't know if my questions is clear, but I was suggested to use javascript for doing this, and I don't realy know how.

Comment: Since JavaScript is an interpreted language, you need an interpreter. For the interpreter to run, you need some other language.

Comment: *"For the interpreter to run, you need some other language."* No, you don't need another *language*. You just need a JavaScript engine. V8 (Google's JavaScript engine), for instance, is a compiled executable. You don't need another language runtime (Python, the JVM, perl, whatever) to run it.

Comment: Which is what I meant: You need V8.